# How to import a file into another python file without it registering as a module

Tags: python, module, directory, chess, modulenotfounderror

on my desktop i have a folder called 'programming', in that folder there is another folder called 'Chessbot', and inside that folder there are two files, 'ChessEngine.py' and 'ChessMain.py'.

I am trying to import ChessEngine.py into ChessMain.py, but when i try to it keeps registering chessengine.py as a module and it results in a module not found error.

In 'ChessMain.py', this is the first line:

```
from Chessbot import ChessEngine
```

obviously I am trying to import this file 'ChessEngine.py', but when I run the code, it says
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Chessbot'`

obviously it thinks that Chessbot is a module rather than a file, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty file `__init__.py` and put under `Chessbot` and maybe under `programming` too. This will make the directories be considered a `module`.

If you're interested in how the python modules and imports work, feel free to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/11556476).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Chessbot is not a module, it is a directory containing two .py files.

The problem here is that you are literally referencing Chessbot as a module when it is not.

Files held in the same directories can simply be imported so remove the `from Chessbot` and simply `import ChessEngine`

Here is my ChessEngine.py:

```
def doAChess():
    print("Did a chess!")
```

Here is my ChessMain.py:

```
import ChessEngine
ChessEngine.doAChess()
```

I would highly recommend following some beginner python tutorials and reading the documentation

Answer (score 0):

**If you have two files in the middle of the folder, then you can import the functionality you need as follows:**

1. No need to import the file from the folder itself

```py
from Chessbot import ChessEngine
```

2. You can import the file itself and then call the required fam functional using a dot

```py
import ChessEngine

ChessEngine.your_func()

ChessEngine.your_variable
```

3. Or you can import the functionality you need right from the file without importing the file itself right away

```py
from ChessEngine import your_func, your_variable

your_func()
print(your_variable)
```